# Ruby on Rails UI Layer - managing divs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby web application and I want to structure the UI layer to have a few templates made up of a number of various divs - something like header, footer, and other things that will repeat throughout pages.

What I am wondering is:
1) Within the Ruby on Rails directory structure, where should these divs live? Somewhere under app/views/layouts ?

2) What is the syntax to import a div in order to still preserve the values of the variables set in the controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to "Partials"

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html (section 3.4)

Specifically, look at the `locals` option.

Layouts are usually in 'views' but you can change where they exist. `views/layouts` will work fine.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just do something like import some_div and it would just render that div? Maybe I am not getting it.